# Android - multiple BitmapShaders with different bitmap and TileMode

Tags: android, image, bitmap, shader, android-canvas

I am currently facing a problem with android's BitmapShader.
Basically, I want to build a circle of images where each of them is masked on a partial arc of the circle
Here's the illustration to help:
[image]

I have managed to actually mask the image into each of partial arc, but the result is not satisfying. I have tried 2 different modes of BitmapShader: CLAMP and REPEAT modes.

[image]

The CLAMP mode of BitmapShader seems to be shared across different BitmapShader, even with different Paint object
Here's the REPEAT mode
[image]

Similar with CLAMP, the tiling properties are shared across different BitmapShaders, eventhough I used different Paint and Bitmap object

Here's the source code:

```
public class CustomMasking extends RelativeLayout {

//images. all of them are 150x150 in size
private static final int[] IMAGES = {
        R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4,
        R.drawable.img5, R.drawable.img6
};

//array of the masked bitmaps
private MaskedBitmap[] maskedBitmaps;
private RectF innerCircle, outerCircle;

//angles and dimensions. centerX and centerY is the center coord of circle
private float angle;
private int centerX=300, centerY=400;
private int innerRadius=150, outerRadius=300;

//paint strokes for debug draw
private Paint redstroke;

public CustomMasking(Context c, AttributeSet set){
    super(c,set);
    this.setWillNotDraw(false);

    //setup paint to debug draw
    redstroke = new Paint();
    redstroke.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    redstroke.setColor(Color.RED);
    redstroke.setStrokeWidth(3);

    innerCircle = new RectF(
            centerX-innerRadius,centerY-innerRadius,
            centerX+innerRadius,centerY+innerRadius
    ); //inner circle with radius=150

    outerCircle = new RectF(
            centerX-outerRadius,centerY-outerRadius,
            centerX+outerRadius,centerY+outerRadius
    ); //outer circle with radius=300

    //calculate angle
    angle = 360f/IMAGES.length;

    //load image and setup mask
    maskedBitmaps = new MaskedBitmap[IMAGES.length];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < IMAGES.length ; i++){
        maskedBitmaps[i] = new MaskedBitmap(IMAGES[i]);
        maskedBitmaps[i].setPath(createPartialArc(i*angle, angle));
    }

}

//method returns a partial arc from 'angle' to 'angle+sweep'
private Path createPartialArc(float angle, float sweep){
    Path p = new Path();
    p.arcTo(outerCircle,angle,sweep);
    p.arcTo(innerCircle,angle+sweep,-sweep);
    p.close();
    return p;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < maskedBitmaps.length ; i++){
        MaskedBitmap mbmp = maskedBitmaps[i];

        //draw the red stroke
        canvas.drawPath(mbmp.getPath(), redstroke);

        //draw the masked image
        canvas.drawPath(mbmp.getPath(), mbmp.getPaint());
    }

}

//custom class to create the shader, etc.
private class MaskedBitmap{
    private Bitmap bmp;
    private BitmapShader shader;
    private Paint paint;
    private Path path;

    public MaskedBitmap(int drawableResId){
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableResId);

        //The screenshots available are on REPEAT and CLAMP modes
        shader = new BitmapShader(bmp, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        path = null;
    }

    public Paint getPaint(){
        return paint;
    }

    public Path getPath(){
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(Path p){
        this.path = p;
    }
}
```

}

What I want to achieve is that of a CLAMP mode, but without the edge copying properties being shared with other BitmapShader, or the REPEAT mode, but to be able to get the center part of the cropped image shown (not the part where the tiling is shown). I've been scratching my head for a day, but none of the solutions I can think of.

Also, I would like to know how can I make BitmapShader masks from the center of the image. If I were to use REPEAT mode, it's giving me a very hard time to calculate the translation of each image using local Matrix, because the tiling line goes across different shaders.

I'd appreciate any answers given. Thank you in advance

Comment: this is because all your R.drawable.img*. have the same dimensions, try for testing enlarge some of them and you will see the difference

Comment: I have tried enlarging the image using CLAMP mode. It works if the image's dimension is actually bigger than the size of the mask. The problem is, the BitmapShader only masks the top left part of the image. If I know how to center them using the local matrix, I'd choose this solution

Comment: use REPEAT with [this](http://pastebin.com/Vj4MQWkj)

Comment: @pksink hmm interesting. By using the computeBounds() method, I could easily setup the masked image's position inside the mask.Thank you for the solution. I'll try this and see what I can do further haaha